# Group records by relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, grouping

I have models, `User` and `Group`, in `many to many` correlation. Users may have 0 groups associated with them. I need to return all the users grouped by their groups, but also those with no groups, something like this:

#### List of all the users

- Group 1

  - user 1
  - user 2
- Group 2

  - user 3
  - user 4
- Ungrouped

  - user 5
  - user 6

I've tried using this:

```
$groups = $this->group->all();

foreach($groups as $group) {
    echo $group->name;
    foreach($group->users as $user) {
        echo $user->name;
    }
}
```

but this only returns those users which belong to a group.

Is there any elegant way native to Laravel to acomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Nativelly no, but you can do it in laravel way as well.

example:

```
$groups = Groups::with('users')->all();

foreach($groups as $group){
    echo $group->name;
    foreach($group->users as $user){
        echo $user->name;
    }
}

$usersWithoutGroups = User::has('groups', '<', 1)->get();
echo 'Without Groups';
foreach($group->users as $user){
    echo $user->name;
}
```

Comment: Maximilian thanks, how could I then combine the two results to get `['Group 1' => ['User 1', 'User 2'], 'Group 2' => ['User 3', 'User 4'], 'No Group' => ['User 5', 'User 6']]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a good way to do this with Eloquent as it doesn't really account for these types of scenarios where you are trying to get results from a relation where a relation doesn't exist.  You can use `has()` to load relations with 0 results, but if there is no group there to start with, it won't do you much good.

I'd suggest using the query builder where this type of thing can be done in a single query using left join and coalesce on the nulls to return 'Ungrouped' instead.

```
$results = DB::table('users')
    ->selectRaw('group_concat(users.name) as user_list, coalesce(groups.name, \'Ungrouped\') as group_name')
    ->leftJoin('group_user', 'group_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->leftJoin('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
    ->groupBy('groups.name')
    ->get();

foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $result->group_name;
    $users = explode(',', $result->group_name);
    foreach($users as $user) {
        echo $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: user3158900 thanks for your time. For some reason, I'm getting `Trying to get property of non-object` on `echo $user->name;`. If I just do `echo $user;` I only get `string(9) "Ungrouped" string(12) "Test Group 1"`. What could be the reason of this?

Comment: Oh sorry, stupid mistake.  Explode returns an array, not an object.  That should be giving you all your groups you have.  Try removing the `->get()` at the end and instead try `->toSql()` and echo out results.  It should give you the sql which you can run manually to see the results.